# Duplicate objects - nodejs, express, mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to nodejs and I'm doing a full stack developer challenge from devchallenges.io (Shoppingify). I am trying to implement the following behavior https://www.loom.com/share/452290782c574178a35034fdf0322186. In the video, the user can add a new item to either a new category or an existing one. Below, I'm trying to implement this behavior.  I'm currently testing the api in postman.

My thought process was to first of all check if the categories are empty so if there are no items. If this is the case then a new category model should be created with the name, note and image inserted into the items array inside of the category and the {category} to be the name of the category object.

If there are already items, then we check to see if the {category} name is equal to the category value in the request body. If it is, then we push the itemObject which includes the {name, note, image, category} into the items array otherwise we create a whole new category.

The issue occurs when creating a new category after the first one is created. I can push {name, note, image, category} into items just fine in the first category but if I create another new category and try to push {name, note, image, category} into items, it works but it also creates a new category which is what I don't want it to do.

The issue demonstration link is here: https://www.loom.com/share/69d3aca988e748dd9e0f52deaa256c79

```
// @route    POST api/category
// @desc     Add category and items
// @access   Private
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty(),
    check('category', 'Category is required').notEmpty(),
  ],
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array(),
      });
    }

    const { name, note, image, category } = req.body;

    const itemObject = { name, note, image, category };

    try {
      let categoryItem = await Category.find({
        user: req.user.id,
      });
      //   check if category object are empty
      if (categoryItem.length === 0) {
        const newCat = new Category({
          user: req.user.id,
          name: category,
          items: itemObject,
        });
        await newCat.save();
        categoryItem = await Category.find({
          user: req.user.id,
        });
        res.json(categoryItem);
      } else if (categoryItem.length !== 0) {
        //   check if category name already exists
        categoryItem.map(async (cat) => {
          if (cat.name.toLowerCase() === category.toLowerCase()) {
            cat.items.push(itemObject);
            await cat.save();
            categoryItem = await Category.find({
              user: req.user.id,
            });
            res.json(categoryItem);
          } else {
            //   create new category
            const newCat = new Category({
              user: req.user.id,
              name: category,
              items: itemObject,
            });
            await newCat.save();
            categoryItem = await Category.find({
              user: req.user.id,
            });
            res.json(categoryItem);
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  items: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      note: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      image: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      editing: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Category = mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
```

json output

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6201806c722625eb8b2df60a",
        "user": "61c63fc7bbb7b6f35949f078",
        "name": "meat",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "chicken",
                "note": "",
                "image": "",
                "editing": false,
                "_id": "6201806c722625eb8b2df60b"
            },
            {
                "name": "turkey",
                "note": "",
                "image": "",
                "editing": false,
                "_id": "62018077722625eb8b2df611"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "6201808c722625eb8b2df619",
        "user": "61c63fc7bbb7b6f35949f078",
        "name": "fish",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "salmon",
                "note": "",
                "image": "",
                "editing": false,
                "_id": "6201808c722625eb8b2df61a"
            },
            {
                "name": "mackarel",
                "note": "",
                "image": "",
                "editing": false,
                "_id": "620180a2722625eb8b2df626"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "620180a2722625eb8b2df624",
        "user": "61c63fc7bbb7b6f35949f078",
        "name": "fish",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "mackarel",
                "note": "",
                "image": "",
                "editing": false,
                "_id": "620180a2722625eb8b2df625"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you better explain what is the behavior that you are expecting? Or at least attach a JSON output of what you want

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: The code insert the item to the correct category but also creates a new category which is what I don't want.

Comment: Adding an item to a category is a MongoDB database _update_ operation. I think you are adding an item to the items array. Normally, its a PATCH request, as you are modifying the items field in the category document.